# Understanding requirement of logic question

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I have a statement like this: if 4x - 3 is even then x is odd. What does providing the predicate for the starting assumption and the predicate for the concluding assumption for a proof by contraposition mean?

Current I have some like this as the predicate for the starting assumption:

> P(x) = 4x - 3 is odd

Is this sufficient? or do I need to go further.

Comment: suppose x is even

Comment: Dont understand what you mean

Comment: I don't understand your question, could you ask it in a different way?

Comment: The question states that: Consider the following statement:
For every integer x, if 4x - 3 is even, then x is odd.
Answer the following questions about this statement.
Provide the predicate for the starting assumption for a proof by contraposition for the given statement.

I have been able to answer question for the actual proof be contraposition, but I don't understand what this question entails.

Comment: As a side note, can you find an integer $x$ for which $4x-3$ is even?

Comment: Nope can't think of any, that's not the exact question, just trying to understand an aspect of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you have to prove $P \implies Q$ for two propositions $P$ and $Q$, the contraposition asks you to prove the equivalent statement $\neg Q \implies \neg P$, where $\neg$ stands for negation.

Therefore, for attempting a proof by contraposition, the starting assumption is $\neg Q$, where $Q$ is the conclusion of the original statement.

Similarly, the conclusion of a proof by contraposition, is $\neg P$, where $P$ is  the starting assumption of the original statement.

In our case, we have $P = 4x-3$ is even and $Q = x$ is odd.

Hence, $\neg Q = \mathit{x}$ *is even* and $\neg P = \mathit{4x-3}$ *is odd* are the starting assumption and conclusion of a proof by contraposition, respectively.

Therefore, for attempting a proof by contraposition, you start with the fact that $x$ is even. You should now show that $4x-3$ is odd,  which is the conclusion,using the starting assumption.

Note : In our case, it turns out the conclusion is true if $x$ is any integer, so starting assumption is somewhat stronger than required.

Comment: So I will be right to say `¬Q=x  is even` is the predicate of the starting assumption?

Comment: Yes, you will be right

Answer (score 0):

As we know, to prove `P -> Q`, you have to ensure that there is no situation in which `P` is false and `Q` is true.

Based on this statement, your questions looks like this:

`Even(4x - 3) -> Odd(x)`

where, `Even(x):  x is even and Odd(x) : x is odd`

To prove the statement by, Proof by contraposition, you need to know that

`P -> Q ≡ ~Q -> ~P`, where ~a is negation of a.   -------- (I)

So, you need to assume about `~Q` or more specifically `~Odd(x)`.

Assume, `Odd(x)` is false, meaning x is even.

x = 2k, for any arbitrary Integer k.

Then `4x - 3` = `4(2k) - 3` = 8k - 3.

We know 8k is Even, and 3 is odd. Also Even - Odd = Odd.

This means `Even(4x - 3)` is also false.

As we proved it's contrapositive, we know by (I) that the claim is also true.

QED.

Comment: Thanks, I had actually proved the statement, was trying to understand getting the predicate of an assumption.